Remove or Hide the results pane side bar buttons (Save to CSV/XML etc)
How do you remove the buttons on the right hand side of the results pane in Azure Data Studio (ADS)?
The buttons fixed height means multi query result sets take up (at least) twice the vertical space it could:

I can't find a user setting or preference that either hides the buttons or moves them to a different part of the screen

I don't believe there is an setting/preference for it. Though SSMS' spacing is almost identical, and it doesn't have those buttons.

The difference with SSMS is you can drag the results pane smaller, and the results bunch together. In ADS the buttons keep the row height and the results don't get closer together


To remove the buttons on the right-hand side of the results pane in Azure Data Studio you can follow below procedure:
Go to File --> Preferences --> Settings --> Data, select Query editor and uncheck Results: Show Action Bar as shown below:

Then you will be able to hide the side bar buttons as shown below:

